# Como recuperar um braço deletado no Git

Tags: git

Eu deletei um braço do git via `git branch -D <nomedobraco>` e eu  preciso dos commits que havia feito nesse braço, preciso restaurá-lo. O problema é que ele não havia sido enviado para o remoto, então, não tem como puxá-lo para o local. Tem como recuperar um braço nessa situação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, há como recuperá-lo, pois a referência do braço foi deletada, mas os *commits* não. Basta descobrir o *SHA1* de um commit do braço e realizar *checkout* até ele. Estando nesse *commit*, basta criar um braço a partir dele e, então, você terá um braço novo, mas com os mesmos *commits* do braço deletado. Vamos passo-a-passo:

Esse commando abaixo irá listar os commits realizados no projeto e assim você poderá identificar qual o último commit do braço deletado.

```
git reflog
```

Encontrado o commit, pegue o *SHA1* dele e execute o comando abaixo para ir até o commit.

```
git checkout <sha1>
```

Agora, basta criarmos um braço a partir de onde estamos.

```
git checkout -b <nomedobraco>
```

Pronto, temos o nosso braço. Isso tudo poderia ser resumido a um único commit caso você já saiba o *SHA1* do *commit*:

```
git checkout -b <nomedobraco> <sha1>
```