# Recuperar feature do repositório git

Tags: git, commit, sourcetree

Crie um feature para meu novo projeto, realizei alguns commits e logo em seguinda o push para a nuvem.
deletei a minha feature local e acabei deletando a feature da nuvem também.

**Gostaria de saber se tem como recuperar uma feature deletada da nuvem no meu git? se sim, qual procedimento deve ser feito?**

OBS: Estou utilizando o SouceTreen para gerenciar as versões dos meus arquivos.

Comment: Possível duplicata.<br>
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204286/como-recuperar-um-bra%C3%A7o-deletado-no-git =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine um cenário em que você tenha usado um rebase em sua branch e as tenha perdido em n commits ou tenha feito um reset --hard.

Agora todos os commits foram perdidos ou rebased, simplesmente colocados, eles não são mais reconhecíveis usando seus IDs de commit anteriores.

Se você gostaria de voltar ao estado do repo antes de fazer o rebase ou resetar --hard, você pode usar o git reflog.

O Git mantém internamente um log de estado do seu HEAD e todas as mudanças que foram feitas nele.

```
 git reflog

7b4ab0e HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 3-dummy to master
a256440 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): Fixes Dummy Issue
d848c34 HEAD@{2}: commit: Fixes issue#3   
09dca41 HEAD@{3}: commit: Issue 3 first cut
7b4ab0e HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to 3-dummy
7b4ab0e HEAD@{5}: clone: from git@github.com:abishekk92/box.git
```

Se você notar, todas as mudanças no estado do HEAD são registradas. Quando soubermos a que estado queremos mover a HEAD para,

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{x}
```

Caso você tenha alterações e não pode fazer uma reinicialização forçada para um determinado reflog, mas ainda quiser as alterações do commit perdido.

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Obs: E também o git limpa seu blob, logo que ele atinge 5.000 objetos, por isso não seria possível redefinir a um estado muito antigo, a menos que você tenha configurado o git para fazê-lo.

Comment: Por favor, detalhe melhor a sua resposta.

Comment: o comando git reflog possibilita você recuperar "qualquer" coisa q foi apagada, mesmo que tenha sido apagado permanentemente, da uma lida na documentação que explica tudo certinho como funciona

Comment: Não, não era pra detalhar melhor pra mim, e nos comentários, e sim na sua resposta! ;-) O objetivo do StackOverflow é servir de repositório de conhecimento para desenvolvedores, através de perguntas e respostas, então, se alguém algum dia tiver essa dúvida, sua resposta pode ser útil. Mas, do jeito que está ela não explica nada, não dá nenhum exemplo, então poderia ser melhorada. Sem contar que você está baseando a maior parte da resposta em um link externo, mas, se no futuro esse link deixar de funcionar, sua resposta perde a utilidade, por isso a importância de detalhar pelo menos o mínimo!

Comment: Prontinho, post editado =)